# New Instagram Rate Limits

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

We have created an app to display our own feed on our own website. However, we're now exceeding the new rate limit of 500 requests per hour. Instagram says our app does not need review and therefore cannot be upgraded to a "Live" app and take advantage of the higher rate limit. How do we get around this? On a side note, this is a lot of trouble to display our own feed on our own website. Sheesh.

Comment: You could cache the data instagram returns. I think requesting new data for each pageview is not necesary. One single data-pull for all users every minute or so should be more than enought

Comment: Thanks - yes, that sounds like it would work. We're running at about 750 requests per hour and about a peak of 200 users in an hour. I was thinking caching one request per hour but would like to make it as "real-time" as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you datafeed is seen by all users, but it's always the same datafeed. So instead of caching it for each user, you could request data each 30 seconds (or less) and store the results in a DB. You should then try always to read feed data from DB but if 15 seconds have passed you should request data from Instagram again.

That would make pretty transaparent to your users

Comment: That's even better. Even if we just request from the API and save to DB or a text file every 15 sec and always called the data from the DB or text file, that would be acceptable I think. So, a maximum of a 15 sec delay from posting on Instagram to appearance on the website and it keeps us under the 500 request limit. I like it!

Comment: Quick update - we registered a new client on Instagram, got a new access token and updated our code to cache the api request every 15 seconds (max of 240 per min). Works great! We fetch the feed save it in a .json file and serve it up to visitors if the .json file modified time is < 15 seconds ago. At the 15 second mark, we make the call to Instagram and save a new .json file. Shout out to the folks over here for some code ideas to work with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558078/caching-instagram-api-requests-using-php